# Ubuntu server 16.04 - dashboard for managing running application / ports

Tags: server, application-development, monitor, amazon-ec2, aws

I am running my ubuntu standard server on AWS EC2 instance.
I have multiple application, each is running on a different port.
I'd like to be able to monitor those applications.
Is there any dashboard that monitors and check the status of each application?

So I'll be able to run commands on some application if needed, remotely.
Or even using git commands, restart the applications or update application.

Thanks!

Comment: Its a standard EC2 instance.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 16.04  LTS